# UICollectionViewCells not loading when embedded with UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uitabbarcontroller, uicollectionviewcell

I have two ViewControllers Embedded with UINavigationControllers and a UITabBarController. When I run the program without the UITabBarController the CollectionViews load and work correctly.

My problem is when I embed the UITabBarController the ViewControllers will load but the CollectionViews are empty.

I have tried placing this in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear` `self.filmsCollection.reloadData()` but it will still not load.

I have looked at several other similar questions but the solutions did not work. I'm trying to solve what it is I'm missing to properly load the CollectionViews when embedded in a UITabBarController.

Comment: Can you please check for 3D view of the  collection view added? Or may be a problem your view is not properly accessing from the tabbar ? Please use break points for multiple checks . And please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the storyboard constraints. When I added the UITabBarController it changed the constraints and caused the UICollectionView to not appear correctly.

Solution was to adjust the constraints so that the UICollectionView would appear.